Reference that heat semigroup is $L^1$ contractive
Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold (i.e. compact and with no boundary) and let $h \in C^\infty(\mathbb R_+ \times M \times M)$ be the heat kernel. Let $u \in L^1(M)$ and define
$$T(t)u(x) := \int_M h(t,x,y) \, u(y) \mathrm dy.$$
I have read several times that $T$ is an $L^1$ contraction, meaning $\|T(t) u\|_{L^1(M)} \leq \|u\|_{L^1(M)}$ for all $t \in \mathbb R_+$ and that this can be proven via duality. However, I cannot find a clear reference for this statement. Can anyone help me out here?

First recall that $h(t, x, y) \geq 0$ for all $t > 0$, $x, y \in M$ and $\int_{M}h(t, x, y)\,dy = 1$. These follow from the fact that $T(t)u$ is the solution to the heat equation with initial data $u$, evaluated at time $t$. To prove the first you use $u = \delta_{y}$ (approximate $\delta_y$ by nonnegative functions and use the maximum principle). To prove the second, use $u = 1$. A reference is chapter 6 of "Partial Differential Equations I" by M. Taylor.
We have
\begin{align}
\|T(t)u\|_{L^1(M)} &= \int_{M}\left|\int_{M}h(t, x, y)u(y)\,dy \right|\,dx \\
&\leq \int_{M}\int_{M}h(t, x, y)|u(y)|\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{M}\int_{M}h(t, x, y)\,dx|u(y)|\,dy \\
&= \int_{M}|u(y)|\,dy \\
&= \|u\|_{L^1(M)}.
\end{align}
Here we used the symmetry $h(t, x, y) = h(t, y, x)$ which is evident from the formula $h(t, x, y) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}e^{-t\lambda_j}u_j(x)u_j(y)$, where $u_j$s are orthonormal eigenfunctions of $-\Delta$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.
